# Can you go to an Apple store for a problem with a product you bought in another country?

Tags: apple-store, applecare

I got an iPhone in Germany, but I'm in Japan now. The camera has got some issues, and I wonder if I can go to a Japanese apple store with my problem or do I have to wait until I'm visiting Europe/Germany the next time?

Comment: Is the iPhone covered by [AppleCare+](http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/)?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely go to an Apple retail store if one is convenient. Worst case, they can assist you in setting up service in the country of origin if that is needed, but in many cases, parts are universal should you need an actual hardware repair.

Both countries you mention also have web service, so you can set up service and possibly a repair without needing a trip to the store.

Technically, Apple *could* ask you to mail the product back to the country where you bought it, but my experience is that is reserved for rare circumstances and not the normal procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the iPhone warranty is limited to the country of purchase.

I was able to find this:

> IMPORTANT RESTRICTION FOR iPHONE AND iPAD SERVICE.
>
> Apple may restrict warranty service for iPhone and iPad to the country
>   where Apple or its Authorized Distributors originally sold the Apple
>   Product.

http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/iphone-english-uk-africa.html

Also, once when I was at an Apple service center in India, I saw a big board they had put up which said "iPhone support is provided only to locally purchased devices."

But I guess there is no harm in trying. These things are not always set in stone.

Comment: You are correct that there is language allowing Apple to refuse service, but the worst I've seen is you have to call back to the country of origin and arrange service for where you are. They will then contact a local service provider or ask you to troubleshoot it remotely and ship it to an appropriate service center. Going into an actual Apple store often yields much higher level of service without reseller/partner restrictions like you experienced.

Comment: @bmike: You are probably right. You will have better luck with an Apple store than with re-sellers/partners. Re-sellers are pretty bad at diagnosing issues on the spot; most require you to leave it with them and a replacement takes forever.